# Can assertEquals only be applicable for same data types?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, parameterized

Can AssertEquals be applied for different data typed input and outputs ?When I have applied AssertEquals to different data typed input and output,the AssertEquals gets striked off..and even the successful test case are not passing ?

What I meant by different data typed input and outputs means..Say example,Consider a program to check whether a number is even or odd.The input to this program is a number which is 'int' data type and output to this program is a 'String' datatype,which prints the number is "even" or "odd".

Here is the code

```
package BasicTesting;

import java.util.*;
class EvenOdd
{
    
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.println("Enter any integer to check whether its odd or even...");
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;
    
    i = ob.nextInt();
    OddEven(i);
    
  }
  public static void OddEven(int i) {
      if(i%2==0)
        {
            System.out.println("You entered an even number");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You entered an odd number");
        }
  }
}
```

This is the JUnit test case I have tried to written...but there are some errors in it because of the different data types.
package BasicTesting;

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class EvenOddTest {

    @Test
    public static void test() {
        
        

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EvenOdd a=new EvenOdd();
        //int res=a.OddEven(10);
        assertEquals("You entered an even number",a.OddEven(10));
        
    }

}
```

Please help me to write parameterized JUnit test case.Hope you will help.

Comment: What do you mean by "different data typed input and outputs"? Show us what you are trying to do otherwise we can only guess. Also take a read of the docs, they typically do a good job to explain how it works: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html

Comment: I mean, it can be applied, it'll just always fail.

Comment: I am using JUnit 4 framework.

Comment: What I meant by different data typed input and outputs is input to the above program to check whether a number is odd or even is an number which is of 'int' datatype and output is a 'string' datatype which tells us even or odd.I want to write JUnit parameterized test cases for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your test is nonsensical.  You can't compare the result of a call to `OddEven` to anything.  It is a `void` method.  It doesn't return anything.

(Presumably the "different types" the compiler is talking about are `String` and `void` or `Void`.  But `void` not really a type at all.  Or at least, not in any useful sense.)

Unfortunately, a method whose sole observable action is to write to standard output is *difficult* to write a unit test for.   You would need to use a mocking framework and mock `System.out`.   (Or use `System.setOut` so replace standard output with some stream that allows you to *capture* the output.)

A better idea (and a better design) is to have your `evenOdd` method NOT write to standard output.  Instead, have it return a `boolean`, and let the caller write the message ... or do something else with the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to compare different data types, like int with long something like this -

```
Assert.assertEquals(23.374f, 23.374d)
```

You can wrap the values in BigDecimal and compare like this -

```
float f = 23.374f;
double  d = 23.374d;
BigDecimal decimal_f = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(f));
BigDecimal decimal_d = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d));
assertEquals(decimal_f,decimal_d);
```

Note - Usage of BigDecimal will also add some overhead.